# Setting up sublime text 2 with activeperl?

Tags: perl, sublimetext2, activeperl

New to using sublime text 2 and I'm wondering how to get it to point to the activeperl.exe (on win7).

I'm testing out the compiler to make sure it works with something simple like:

```
$x = 1;
$print "$x";
```

But it gives me guff about how $x isn't a recognized syntax. I did point ST2 to my python executable, but I forgot which file in the labyrinth I was supposed to edit the path to.

Comment: You said "python" executable, have you tried using the "perl" executable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me, taken from: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=935014

1. Click "Preferences -> Browse Packages"
2. Navigate to the "Perl" subfolder
3. Create a file called "Perl.sublime-build" with the following content:

```
    {
      "cmd": ["perl", "-w", "$file"],
      "file_regex": ".* at (.*) line ([0-9]*)",
      "selector": "source.perl"
    }
```

4. Manually set the build system by clicking "Tools -> Build System -> Perl"
5. You can now run your Perl script by mashing Ctrl+B

I am running this version of ActiveState Perl:

```
C:\>perl --version
Binary build 1402 [295342] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Oct  7 2011 15:49:44
```

Comment: I did this a little differently. I created the "Perl.sublime-build" file by choosing "Tools -> Build System -> New Build System" and then used the content from step 3 there. It works fine on my Mac running OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Worked great - but how can you set the verbosity level? It is printing out a lot more in the console that I would like to see...

Comment: Remember to remove .txt extension from the file and works like a charm.

Comment: Work like a charm, but somethime no response result, modify any word in pl file and rebuild you will got it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the version 3 of Sublime Text and to run perl programs in this editor, you should:

1. Click *"Preferences -> Browse Packages"*
2. Navigate to the *"Sublime Text"* subfolder library *"Lib"*
3. Create a file called `Perl.sublime-build` with the following content:

```
{
  "cmd": ["perl", "-w", "$file"],
  "file_regex": ".* at (.) line ([0-9])",
  "selector": "source.perl"
}
```

4. Manually set the build system by clicking *"Tools -> Build System -> Perl"*
5. You can now run your Perl script by pressing `Ctrl+B`.

Attention: the file `Perl.sublime-build` should be created in this root diretory:  `\Sublime Text 3\Lib`.